# Is it possible to propagate variable from a Jenkins pipeline job script to loaded jenkinsfile script?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to know if it's possible to pass a variable define in a jenkins pipeline job to a loaded script like.
The loaded script

Pipeline Job

```
node {

     // Some declaration and code

    stage('Prepare deploy') {
        // Create a talbe for the servers lists
        def servers = [:]

        // For each server know, if deployment is enabled
        // deploy resources
        params.each { srv, value ->
        if ("$value" == "true"){
            // add the current current to the enabled servers
            servers["Server ${srv}"] = {

                // Define specific variable
                String SERVER=props."SRV_${srv}"
                String CONF=env.DEPLOY_HOME + "/${srv}"

               // Install server - the SERVER and CONF variable need to be propagate to the others scripts
               load env.JENKINSFILES_DIRECTORY + "/server-configuration"
               load env.JENKINSFILES_DIRECTORY + "/server-deploiement"
               load env.JENKINSFILES_DIRECTORY + "/server-postconfig"
               load env.JENKINSFILES_DIRECTORY + "/server-start"
            }
        }
    }
    parallel servers
    }

}
```

---

server-configuration file

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy​
node{
     // Some declaration
     stage('configure serveur'){
          // The variable SERVER and CONF must be visible here
          // is it possible ?
          sh "ssh -X " + env.USER +"@${SERVER} 'sh echo \"${CONF}\"'"
     }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I got another hint on your script: since the loaded scripts have their own node block the parallel call should not be done inside a node block as this will only block a node for no reason. If the runtime is a few secs only this won’t hurt. However if there’s a shortage in nodes you may block one node until another one will be free... Just saying:)

Comment: Hum... Thanks. If I understand what you said, it's better if I do that ? def server .... node{ } .... parralel server ? (parralel call is inside the node ?) Or I suppress the node block in the loaded script ?

Comment: This will depend on your need. If you'll be able to reuse that node I'd rather prefer it that way as - for large Jenkins instances - opening a new node block may take up to some minutes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I made some tries. So, for my needs, It's better is I delete the node block in server-configuration file. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`withEnv` is what you are looking for

```
node {

 // Some declaration and code

stage('Prepare deploy') {
    // Create a talbe for the servers lists
    def servers = [:]

    // For each server know, if deployment is enabled
    // deploy resources
    params.each { srv, value ->
    if ("$value" == "true"){
        // add the current current to the enabled servers
        servers["Server ${srv}"] = {

           // Install server - the SERVER and CONF variable need to be propagate to the others scripts
withEnv(["SERVER=props.SRV_${srv}","CONF=env.DEPLOY_HOME + ${srv}"]){
           load env.JENKINSFILES_DIRECTORY + "/server-configuration"
           load env.JENKINSFILES_DIRECTORY + "/server-deploiement"
           load env.JENKINSFILES_DIRECTORY + "/server-postconfig"
           load env.JENKINSFILES_DIRECTORY + "/server-start"
        }
}
    }
}
parallel servers
}
}
```

server-config

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy​
node{
 // Some declaration
 stage('configure serveur'){
      // The variable SERVER and CONF must be visible here
      // is it possible ?
      sh "ssh -X " + env.USER +"@${env.SERVER} 'sh echo \"${env.CONF}\"'"
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried withEnv and it worked. I was about to write a comment when I saw your answer